# Create Comma Delimiter in Select Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, delimiter, for-xml-path

I have here a query that gives two rows of results:

```
SELECT @SlsChannelDiv= a.division,@SlsChannel= a.department
                    FROM dbo.m_SalesCode a left join dbo.m_SalesCode b 
                    ON a.up1_code=b.sales_code left join vwEmployeeAds v 
                    ON a.user_id=v.login
                    WHERE v.login = @SalesLogin
```

I would like to use the `@SlsChannel` parameter for other queries.

`Select * from wo where sales in (@SlsChannel)`

but this always gives the first row of results.

I can modify my first query by giving an XML path:

```
SELECT @SlsChannelDiv= a.division,@SlsChannel= a.department
                        FROM dbo.m_SalesCode a left join dbo.m_SalesCode b 
                        ON a.up1_code=b.sales_code left join vwEmployeeAds v 
                        ON a.user_id=v.login
                        WHERE v.login = @SalesLogin For XML PATH ('')
```

However, I get an error such as: `The FOR XML clause is not allowed in a ASSIGNMENT statement.`

Is it possible to create a `@SLSChannel` value, comma delimited, in an `In` parameter?

Comment: Do you want to replace any individual `@SlsChannel` *item* that is NULL with the corresponding `@SlsChannelDiv` item or replace the entire `@SlsChannel` *list* with the other list when the `@SlsChannel` list is NULL?

Comment: no, please read what i wanted to do, in this case the query i want to use is `Select * from wo where sales in (@SlsChannel)` why I have `@SlsChannelDiv= a.division,@SlsChannel= a.department` i have multiple conditions with that

Comment: Yes, that seemed more or less clear, I only tried to reconcile it with the note that you added later, the one where you said that `sometimes @SlsChannel has no value so I'll use @SlsChannelDiv`. But as you have now removed it, I guess @bluejaded's suggestion should do just fine.

Comment: yes sorry for confusing note, what I mean actually I use the query for multiple condition. but mistaken write the note like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select * from wo where sales in (SELECT a.department
                FROM dbo.m_SalesCode a left join dbo.m_SalesCode b 
                ON a.up1_code=b.sales_code left join vwEmployeeAds v 
                ON a.user_id=v.login
                WHERE v.login = @SalesLogin)
```

How about querying it like this? :)

Comment: oh yeah of course it's possible, but I shoul modify most of my code, but i'm afraid, that my query has multiple conditions, sometimes `@SlsChannel` has no value so I'll use `@SlsChannelDiv`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you want your first query to return multiple rows right? I guess you should not assign any variable to it because it will really return one row. You can just use a temporary table instead, insert the query results for the first query. Then, do this "Select * from wo where sales in (Select column from #temptable). No need for comma delimited values.

Comment: ah ya got it, yep if I assign to any variable it'll give one value only. okay I'll do some modify on my code